# Stuck with Doctrine Extensions + Zend 2 with YAML bindings

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, yaml

I'm having trouble making sense of the examples for getting the Gedmo doctrine extensions working. I don't fully understand all the various configuration bits but this is what I think the relevant part is:

```
$cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
$yamlDriver = new Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver(array(APPLICATION_PATH . $options['mappingDir']));
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($yamlDriver);
$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($options['connection'], $config);
```

That's my current setup, and it's working. The YamlDriver points to my Yaml configuration files; my entities are in `APPLICATION_PATH . '/entities/'`. I couldn't figure out how to put my entities into a namespace, which could be part of the problem -- I just added `APPLICATION_PATH . '/entities/'` to my include path.

What I think I need to do is the following (this is taken from the doctrineextensions demo):

```
$cache = new Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
// standard annotation reader
$annotationReader = new Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
$cachedAnnotationReader = new Doctrine\Common\Annotations\CachedReader(
    $annotationReader, // use reader
    $cache // and a cache driver
);
// create a driver chain for metadata reading
$driverChain = new Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DriverChain();
// load superclass metadata mapping only, into driver chain
// also registers Gedmo annotations.NOTE: you can personalize it
Gedmo\DoctrineExtensions::registerAbstractMappingIntoDriverChainORM(
    $driverChain, // our metadata driver chain, to hook into
    $cachedAnnotationReader // our cached annotation reader
);

// Replaced their entity annotations with my Yaml driver
$yamlDriver = new Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver(array(APPLICATION_PATH . $options['mappingDir']));

// register annotation driver for our application Entity namespace
$driverChain->addDriver($yamlDriver , 'Entity');
```

And then add `$driverChain` as with `setMetadataDriverImpl()`.

However, that's not working -- probably because you can't use driverChain without having your entities in a namespace to point the specific driver at?

Then I need to get the event manager working:

```
$evm = new Doctrine\Common\EventManager();

$sortableListener = new Gedmo\Sortable\SortableListener;
$sortableListener->setAnnotationReader($cachedAnnotationReader);
$evm->addEventSubscriber($sortableListener);
```

But that doesn't work -- when I pass the $evm to my entity manager, I get an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver::getLocator() in D:\Jeremy\htdocs\umr\library\Gedmo\Mapping\ExtensionMetadataFactory.php on line 157

If anyone can shed any light on this I would be most grateful! I have a suspicion that the first part, with the chained metadata drivers, is only necessary if you're using the classes mentioned in `registerAbstractMappingIntoDriverChainORM()`, which I am not -- so if all I need to do is get the event manager going, then great -- I'll tackle the other part another day.